# If $\ell_{A_\mathfrak{p}}(N)<\infty$, then is it true that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,E(A/\mathfrak{q}))=0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}\subset A$ distinct prime ideals of the same height, $N$ an $A_\mathfrak{p}$-module of finite length. Then is it true that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,E(A/\mathfrak{q}))=0,$$
where $E(A/\mathfrak{q})$ is the injective hull of $A/\mathfrak{q}$?

The main trouble here is that $N$ may not be finitely generated over $A$. If it were, I would use formulas like
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Ass}\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,E(A/\mathfrak{q}))&=&\operatorname{Supp}_AN\cap\operatorname{Ass}E(A/\mathfrak{q})\
&=&V(\mathfrak{p})\cap\lbrace\mathfrak{q}\rbrace\
&=&\emptyset.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Presumably $E$ stands for injective envelope?

Comment: @Steve Yes; Sorry, I edited that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\phi\in\operatorname{Hom}_A(N,E(A/\mathfrak{q}))$, and $\phi(n)=e\neq0$. We will derive a contradiction.

Since $N$ is of finite length over $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, $\mathfrak{p}^kN=0$ for some $k$. Since $\mathfrak{p}\not\subset\mathfrak{q}$, $\exists a\in\mathfrak{p}^k\backslash\mathfrak{q}$, so $a$ acts as a unit on $E(A/\mathfrak{q})$. Then
$$0=\phi(an)=ae\neq0,$$
a contradiction.